# Sort and show data in nested object - laravel

Tags: arrays, object, laravel-5

hi i have problem of printing array object. i want to sort by accomadates the whole record like expected result.

```
    object:
     "name":1,
     "id":1,
         "occ":  [{  
             "accomadates":1},

                 {  
             "accomadates":2}
     {  
             "accomadates":3}],
   "name":2,
     "id":2,
         "occ":  [{  
             "accomadates":2},

                 {  
             "accomadates":3}
                 }],
```

now its print like:

```
id 1 :accomadates  1
id 1 :accomadates  2
id 1 :accomadates  3
id 2 :accomadates  2
id 2 :accomadates  3
```

expected result:

```
id 1 :accomadates  1
id 2 :accomadates  1
id 1 :accomadates  2
id 1 :accomadates  3
id 2 :accomadates  3
```

can i do in Laravel? pls help me. thank you all

edit:

```
//this is how i print using foreach loop

@foreach($ojects as $object)

   @foreach(object->occ as $occ)
      id {{$oject->name}} :accomadates  {{$occ->accomadates}} 
   @endforeach
<br>
@endforeach
```

i want print exactly like :

```
id 1 :accomadates  1
id 2 :accomadates  1
id 1 :accomadates  2
id 1 :accomadates  3
id 2 :accomadates  3
```

Answer (score 0):

try and convert the array to a Collection using

`$c = collect($c);`

And the sort by property like this:

```
$sorted = $c->sortBy('id');
```

If you want the result to be an Array use

```
$c = $c->toArray();
```

To convert the collection back to an array

Comment: its only sort 1st node. i want print whole record by 'accomadates' value